# How to create mutiple Class-objects on request

Tags: java, class

I recently started creating a game in Java. For this game, I created a class called Tower. Within this class, I have some integer variables and some strings. Now I would like to know if there is a way to create a new Tower object in response to a mouse event.

For example: A click event on the screen should create a new Tower object (then add the coordinates to the Tower object). And, if you click somewhere else on the screen, another Tower object is created with the new coordinates.

I would like something like this since the player would be able to buy multiple towers and place them wherever he or she likes (these towers will have different properties). Is there any way to do this? Is this even possible? If not any suggestions :P?

Comment: Well yes - you have a mouse click handler. What have you tried?

Comment: You can create as many Tower objects as you want with `new Tower(arguments)`, and you might want to keep track of them in a `List<Tower>`

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast responds, I tried just a simple code within the mouse event, but i have to name the tower object. so once i click again the first object is gone.

Comment: i know i can create a new tower. but how do i give them differnt names so i can acces them later on. Or dont i have to give them differnt names withing a list?

Comment: Use a `HashMap`. Also, your `Tower`s should have some kind of associated name or ID to them.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach it's not the final & perfect answer but hope it can be useful for your question

```
LinkedList<Tower> list = new LinkedList<Tower>();
```

On mouse event :

```
list.add(new Tower());
list.get(0).x = 4;
list.get(0).y = 5;
//......
System.out.println("x  = "+list.get(0).x);  
System.out.println("y  = "+list.get(1).y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of some code that will generate five Towers with UUID's - keeping track of each in a HashMap (credit Jack Maney).

You'd just need to modify it to create from an `onClick()` instead of a `for` loop.

```
final class TowerGenerator
{
   private final Map<UUID, Tower> towerMap = new HashMap<UUID, Tower>();

   public void generateFiveTowers()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
         final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
         towerMap.put(uuid, new Tower(uuid));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Anytime :) Love Tower Defense games!